# Caption below of included PDF

Tags: captions, pdfpages

I would like to inlucde a PDF document and add a caption on the bottom of the page. I tried it with the following statements:

```
\begin{landscape}
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.8,landscape,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}\null\vfill\captionof{table}{Caption Text}}]{Test.pdf}
\end{landscape}
```

The PDF gets included and the caption is added but it overlaps the included PDF:
[image]

I have already tried to set `\vspace*{12cm}` but this causes that the caption is moved to the nex page. Is there any way to move the caption below the PDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use \enlargethispage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,caption}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\null\vfill\captionof{table}{blub}}]{example-image}

\includepdf[pagecommand={\null\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}\vfill\captionof{table}{blub}}]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An alternative to `\enlargethispage` would be to use the `offset` parameter of `includepdf` and scale down the pages slightly. This way you can keep your page layout.